# Using image libraries for Mac OS X apps in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsimage

The documentation I've found is terribly unclear on this - what I'd like to do is use the provided Xcode image library (catalog?) on a Mac OS X application.

iOS apps get the benefit of being able to use `UIKit`'s `UIImage` object to quickly reference image files that are loaded into the catalog.

(To wit: `UIImage(imageNamed: "Something")`)

Since I'm writing a Mac OS app and not an iOS app, I don't get UIKit.

I'd assume that since XCode provides me with the same image library file by default on an OS X app, that I'm somehow intended to make use of it.

How do I reference images inside the library? Ideally I'd be able to do something with `NSImage`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this situation, you can use NSImage just like UIImage:

```
NSImage(named: "Something")
```

Comment: To generalize a bit: AppKit and UIKit don't have a 1:1 correspondence, but if you're looking for an equivalent of one in the other, just swapping "NS" and "UI" will very often yield good results.

Comment: Great to know, thanks :) - It seems that a lot of the documentation and articles out there are iOS focused, finding things that are specific to Mac OS are is proving to be difficult as I go through my project.

Comment: Yep, as a Mac developer, you're going to have to sift through piles of iOS noise.  However, Chuck is right, in a lot of cases you can just replace 'UI' with 'NS' and find something very similar.